# AuthenticationTicket SetResources/SetProperties how can I use them?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I currently create a API which should make use of Identity Framework and OpenIddict to actually Login User.

I Actually create a simple Authentication Ticket like that

```
    private AuthenticationTicket CreateTicket(OpenIdConnectRequest connectRequest, OAuthApplication application)
    {
        // Create a new ClaimsIdentity containing the claims that
        // will be used to create an id_token, a token or a code.
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            OpenIddictServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name,
            OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role);

        // Use the client_id as the subject identifier.
        identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject, application.ClientId,
            OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken,
            OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);

        identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name, application.DisplayName,
            OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken,
            OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);

        // Create a new authentication ticket holding the user identity.
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
            new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
            new AuthenticationProperties(),
            OpenIddictServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        ticket.SetScopes(connectRequest.GetScopes());

        ticket.SetResources("resource_server");

        return ticket;
    }
```

However now I set the value "resource_server" on the ticket, is there any way to retrieve it?
I.e. I can get all the Scopes inside my ClaimsPrinicpal, but I couldn't find any way of obtaining the AuthenticationProperties of the ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However now I set the value "resource_server" on the ticket, is there any way to retrieve it?

Sure, assuming you use the default token format and the OpenIddict validation handler, here's an example:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAudiences()
{
    var ticket = (await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme))?.Ticket;
    if (ticket != null)
    {
        return Json(ticket.GetAudiences());
    }

    return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to read it from the context directly? I.e. I'm already authenticated via the annotation?

Comment: @ChristianSchmitt what do you mean exactly by "context"? `HttpContext` is the context, in this case. It's worth noting that authentication results are automatically cached by ASP.NET Core's authentication stack, so this operation execute synchronously if you have decorated your action with `[Authorize(…)]`.

Comment: that's what I wanted to know, actually I tought there is a overhead, to call `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync` twice.